# convert extremely large decimal to bytes

Tags: java, binary, numbers, decimal, converters

How do I convert extremely large (>1MB) decimal numbers to bytes/hex/binary?

For example, the number "300" should be converted to {0x01, 0x2C}. The byte order doesn't matter and {0x2C, 0x01} is also OK.

The source numbers are stored in a prepped file (Without puntuation, whitespace or linebreaks). The largest is [just over 17MB](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/math/digit/m57885161/prime-c.html), although I can't rule out that I'll have a 100MB number in the future. The destination is also a file.

Is there a way that doesn't take ages, or is fail-safe in case it *does* take ages?

I fear using `BigInteger` will take ages and is not fail-save (*ie.* i can't resume half-way if something goes wrong)

I'm not against implementing my own algorithm, although I'm looking for something more efficient than 'check if odd, divide by 2'. I've seen a very efficient implementation of binary to BCD, the [Shift and Add-3](http://www.johnloomis.org/ece314/notes/devices/binary_to_BCD/bin_to_bcd.html) Algorithm, and am looking for a similarly efficient implementation in reverse.

An extra kudos for an implementation that also supports fixed-point numbers (with 1 digit and the rest decimals, *eg.* Pi).

Comment: Why don't you try BigInt, and see if it's fast enough?

Comment: I might, but I'm just a sucker for efficient algorithms

Comment: [Premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: @Zom-B: Whenever you "fear" that something may not be fast enough, you should absolutely test it before you start looking elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me `BigInteger` converts 1M digits into `byte []` in ~39 seconds.  Is it too much for you?

```
Random r = new Random ();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    sb.append ("0123456789".charAt(r.nextInt(10)));

long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger (sb.toString());
byte [] bytes = bi.toByteArray();
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t);
```

About decimals.  Lets assume you have a big decimal in form `<n digits>.<m digits>`.  You want to convert it to binary with `k` bits after dot.  You need to solve an equation: `D/(10^m) = X/(2^k)`, where X is integer.  Here D is your decimal without dot (mantissa of your decimal), X is your binary without dot (mantissa of your binary).  The equation is easy to solve: `X ~ round(D*(2^k)/(10^m))`.  X has to be integer, so we added `round()`.

For example you need to convert 12.34 into binary with 3 bits after dot.

```
n = 2
m = 2
D = 1234
k = 3
X ~ round(D*(2^k)/(10^m)) = round(1234 * 8 / 100) = round(98.72) = 99 = 1100011b
```

Remember that we desired 3 bits after dot, so our answer is 12.34 ~ 1100.011b

All these calculations can be done using BigInteger.

Comment: ok, assuming this problem solved, how do I go about fixed point numbers? `BigDecimal` doesn't have a `toByteArray()` method or similar.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that doesn't take ages, or is fail-safe in case it does take ages?

Nope.

Conversion of a decimal number to binary involves repeatedly multiply a large number by 10.  If you have millions of digits, you have millions of multiplications to perform on very large numbers.

However, it sounds like you haven't actually done the conversion on one of these very large numbers, and you are only *guessing* that it will take a long time.  Before you go any further, I strongly suggest that you benchmark this operation to see how long it actually takes.  (Mikhail's Answer says ~39 seconds, but his code as written doesn't take account of JVM warmup.)

Or better still, code the entire application using BigInteger and *profile* it to determine if there is a performance issue, and where the actual performance bottlenecks are.

Comment: Naïve and generic (in terms of radix) implementations like BigInteger are quadratic time O(n²), so I expected it to take ages, and it seems I'm right. Some statistical testing and extrapolating led me to these numbers: 1MB: 17s, 10MB: 1700sec, 100MB: 170000s = 1.96days -- It suffices for now, but not in the future.

Comment: Well you are probably "screwed" ... as they say ... unless you can find a mathematical breakthrough that allows you to multiply an N-digit binary number by 10 in better than O(N) time.  The best you can hope for is to find a faster "big integer" implementation that reduces the `C2` in `C1 + C2 * N^2`.  And you probably need to switch to C. `O(N^2)` is going to be "ages" for large enough values of `N` no matter what implementation you use.  This problem simply does not scale well.